# Which is the best place to learn Craft CMS with tutorials?

Tags: craft3

I am new to craft cms and would like to learn craft cms with tutorials. I am ready to pay for the subscription but would like to know is there any best place where I can learn the craft ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [CraftQuest](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/30075/57), I'll add a few other learning resources:

- [Craft CMS docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/)
- [Craft Discord group](https://craftcms.com/discord)
- [Craft Stack Exchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com) - which you've obviously found.
- [nystudio107 blog](https://nystudio107.com/blog)
- [Tuts+ Tutorials](https://tutsplus.com/courses/search/Craft+CMS)

Answer (score 4):

[CraftQuest.io](https://craftquest.io/) has some great Craft CMS videos; many are free, but some of the more in-depth ones are not.